# Python: Any simple way to find the name of a variable inputted into a function

Tags: python, function, variables

Anyway to print the name of an inputted variable into a function:

Here is an example of what I mean(NON REPRODUCIBLE):

```
myvar = "sample text"

def printname(variable):
    *code to find variable name*

printname(myvar)
```

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: `printname()` did NOT, in any meaningful sense, receive the variable `myvar`.  It received a value, the string `"sample text"`.  That string has no knowledge about any variables that might refer to it; after all, there could be zero, or more than one such variable.

Answer (score 2):

One good way is to pass a `dict` instead.

```
var_dict = {'myvar':'sample text'}

def printname(var_dict):
    for key in var_dict:
        print(key)

printname(var_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to use `kwargs`. Just have your function have one argument preceded by a double star.

```
myvar = "sample text"
def printname(**vars):
   print(vars)

printname(myvar=myvar)
>>> {'myvar': 'sample text'}
```

Comment: doesn't work. I had to remove `**` and execute `printname(var_dict)` to get result.

Comment: Sorry, had a variable typo

Comment: if I use `x = "sample text"` and `printname(myvar=a)` then I get `{'myvar': 'sample text'}` but I think OP expects `{'x': 'sample text'}`

Comment: but how do you get the variable name only?

Comment: In both anwsers you receice an dictionary, which is a key-value storage. The variable names being the keys, which can be obtained by the `.keys()` function, so `vars.keys()` or  `var_dict.keys()` which will give you a list of variable names then, so you need to index them (i.e. `variable_names = vars.keys(); print(variable_names[0])` would print `myvar`)